# Powershell Where-Object for one of two patterns

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script that will connect to a server and backup all dbs that follow one of two patterns, my current code is the following:

```
#The GetDbInstances function is imported from another file
GetDbInstances $Server $User $Password | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*Type1*" -or $._Name -like "*Type2*" } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $Server -Database $_.Name -BackupFile $TargetPath
    }
```

My problem is in the `{ $_.Name -like "*Type1*" -or $._Name -like "*Type2*" }` part, it simply doesn't run and gives me error

```
$._Name : The term '$._Name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
```

My question is what's the correct syntax for that expression?

Comment: You missed the _ in the second clause.  $_.Name instead of $.Name

Answer (score 0):

Check the second condition variable.

It should be `$_.Name`